# Center <span> between two <button>'s

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I am working with bootstrap v3 and trying to center a `<span class="badge">1</span>` between two buttons, one of which uses the `pull-right` class.

The exact html looks as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Decient</button>
<span class="badge">10</span>
<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Garbage</button>
```

However this results in the following:

[image]

I would like to have the 10 centered but have not been successful. I have tried `pagination-centered`, `text-center`and custom CSS to no avail. Also to provide some additional context, this is in the `caption` div of a `thumbnail`.

The following provides a basic scenario of my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/vvA78/1/

Comment: Can we get the relevant css please

Comment: I am just using 3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Why are people so persistent in not helping themselves.. You want this fixed right? Then give us the info. How do we know what that CSS looks like and what you have tried? What do you mean by *custom CSS*, have you tried `text-align:center;`, we don't know

Comment: @mfunkyside Yes I also tried text-align:center. I did provided the exact CSS that I am currently using, and also mentioned that I have tried pagination-centered and text-center. I was hoping that that would be sufficient for someone to help me.

Comment: @Jon It is bootstrap, you should not be asking him to post CSS from the framework.

Comment: Man tough crowd. It was a simple bootstrap question and I got pounced on.

Comment: @Jon, From my perspective, if there's a tag on the post, then someone answering it should expect to have to know about that subject and the poster shouldn't have to worry about explaining it.

Comment: @AlexMorrise: You 're probably right. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `bootstrap`, just use `text-center` on `house-container` div and `pull-left` on `btn-success`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvA78/3/)

To center vertically just add `margin-top`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvA78/4/)

Of course do not follow the example and don't set `margin-top` to the entire `.badge` class.

Answer (score 1):

.badge is probably an `inline` element. If you make it an `inline-block` or a `block` element, you can center it relative to the parent.

try this:

```
.badge { display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width: 40px; }
```

If it does not work, I'd need a fiddle or a link.